# Finding an equivalence relation based on a partition

Tags: solution-verification, equivalence-relations

I'm trying to solve exercise 1.3 in Aluffi's book 'Chapter Zero':

> Given a partition $\mathscr{P}$ on a set $S$, show how to define a relation on $S$ such that $\mathscr{P}$ is the corresponding partition.

Here is my attempt.

> Let $\mathscr{P} = \{X_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$, where $I$ is an arbitrary indexing set and $X_i \cap X_j = \emptyset$ for any $i \neq j$ in $I$. (That is, $S = \bigsqcup\limits_{\alpha \in I} X_{\alpha}$.) Define the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $S$ by $a \sim b$ if and only if $a,b \in X_{\alpha}$ for some (unique) $\alpha \in I$. It is easy to see that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. Certainly $a \sim a$ since $a$ is in the same set $X_{\alpha}$ as itself; since the $X_{\alpha}$ partition $S$, there exists such an $X_{\alpha}$, and it's unique since the sets in the partition are disjoint.) If $a \sim b$, then $a$ and $b$ live in the same $X_{\alpha}$, so $b$ and $a$ certainly live in $X_{\alpha}$. Finally, if $a,b \in X_{\alpha}$ and $b,c \in X_{\beta}$, then $b \in X_{\alpha} \cap X_{\beta}$, so $X_{\alpha} = X_{\beta}$ since the sets are disjoint, so we have $a \sim c$. The partition into equivalence classes is exactly $\mathscr{P}$ by construction.

How does this look? I. worry my answer isn't sufficiently rigorous.

Comment: That’s fine. $\,$

Comment: I would say it's slightly cleaner to define $a\sim b$ if and only if there exists $\alpha\in I$ such that $a\in X_\alpha$ and $b\in X_\alpha$. Then you don't have to check uniqueness when verifying that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. (Just a minor comment though.)

Comment: I do think I could leave out the word unique, but doesn't that follow immediately from the fact that $\mathscr{P}$ is a partition?